# Threading java - two simultaneous work pools

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

I have a situation as follows:

A SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor is working on a work list where it does some work (usually with concurrent parameter set to 2 or 3). Now everytime a thread dispatched from SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor FINISHES, I want it to add an item (not actually produced/evaluated by the task) to a work pool. This work pool is then worked on by a second SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor and is worked on.

A producer/consumer problem.

Easiest approach?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at BlockingQueue.  Sounds like you need a queue between the two.

Comment: No. I looked and implemented one based on the consumer/producer problem.